# react native crypto wallet connection

Tags: metamask, erc20

i have react native app it works with RVM machines to recycle plastic bottles or something you know. in exchange for that app gives some erc20 tokens (CRB my own) that I have to send to the user's wallet address. So I want to connect my app to wallets like Metamask, Maiar, Ledger.
can anyone guide me how do I do that which library should I use

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look on Moralis, at the moment we don't have a lot of choice
https://github.com/ethereum-boilerplate/ethereum-react-native-boilerplate

Comment: i have used this boilerplate but this only provides for wallet connect and can only connect metamask through this. i want to connect Mairar.